# Understand List of List in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am understanding the concept of generics in Java. I am unable to understand the following lines of code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public final class Main {
    public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<A> listA = new ArrayList<Main.A>();
        //listA.add(new Main.B()); // i understood why this line is an error.

        final List<List<A>> listListA = new ArrayList<List<A>>();
        listListA.add(new ArrayList<Main.A>());
        // Why the above line doesn't throws an error ?
    }

    private class A {
    }


    private final class B extends A {
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean a compiler error, or a runtime error?

Comment: The code compiles. There is no error. http://ideone.com/YetaPJ

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `listA.add(new Main.B())`, this gives a compilation error because `B` is a non-static inner class, which must hold a `this` reference to the outer class. Therefore, instantiating `B` requires a non-static context in the outer class, so it cannot be instantiated in a static method.

In the second case, `ArrayList<A>` extends `List<A>`, so a `List<List<A>>` can also contain instances of `ArrayList<A>`. The reason why this doesn't give an error like the first case is that an instance of `A` isn't actually created, so that is okay.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Only Class with private constructor can't be instantiate..  private class with other than private constructor can be initiated..

Comment: Sigh. @Ravi, look, when the OP says there is an error, I wouldn't claim there is no error if I didn't compile the code and test it myself. It compiled, run, and succeeded without error.

Comment: Ah right, I see. You made a point. However, it isn't because the class is private that you can't instantiate it. I'm updating my answer to reflect why.

Comment: The issue here is not private/public. It's static/non-static. The scope in the `main` function *can* access the private class, which by the way has a public default constructor. It's only because the main function is a static function that it cannot instantiate an inner non-static class.

Comment: @javic, yup, you are right. Confusion with the rules. Let me delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk.

In this line, `final List<A> listA = new ArrayList<Main.A>()`, it created an `ArrayList` to hold Objects of type A. Think of this as an array in which each slot holds A.

In this line, `final List<List<A>> listListA = new ArrayList<List<A>>()` you also create an `ArrayList` but in this case each slot holds a **List of A**.

> listListA.add(new ArrayList());
>          // Why the above line doesn't throws an error ?

The reason it doesn't throw an error is because the statement in valid. You are adding an `ArrayList` of A (in a slot) of the List you created.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles fine without any errors. This line `listListA.add(new ArrayList<Main.A>());` doesn't throw an error because it's a valid Java statement.